# Jekyll collections not rendering

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I've made a Jekyll static web site following this [tutorial](https://learn.cloudcannon.com/jekyll/converting-a-static-site-to-jekyll/). The problem is when I reach the collections's section, I do what is being told but my 'portfolio' collection is not rendering.

These are the Markdown files that composes the collection `_portfolio`.

[image: portfolio]

For example, the file called `google.md` has this content:

```
---
image_path: /img/portfolio/1.jpg
category: Diseño web
project_name: Google
link: https://google.com
---
```

As well the other files, but with different data.

My `config.yml` just has this:

```
collections:
  portfolio:
```

And `portfolio.html` has this code:

```
---
layout: page
title: Portafolio
---
<section class="no-padding" id="portfolio">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row no-gutter">
        {%- for item in site.portfolio -%}
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <a href="{{ item.link }}" class="portfolio-box">
              <img src="{{ item.image_path }}" class="img-responsive" alt="{{ item.project_name }}">
              <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                  <div class="project-category text-faded">
                    {{ item.category }}
                  </div>
                  <div class="project-name">
                    {{ item.project_name }}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        {%- endfor -%}
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

When I inspected the elements in the console y noticed that the page is rendering everything but the content after the `{% for %}` tag.

What am I missing?
Are the Markdown files wrong or is it the 'for' tag?

EDIT: This is the repository [link](https://github.com/Dasapugo4444/jekyll-portal.git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your `collection.docs` array is empty, so, no way to loop in.
You need to generate your documents.

Can you try :

```
collections:
  portfolio:
    output: true
```

Edit : And your configuration file must be named **_config.yml** and NOT **config.yml**.

Comment: Thanks for your response David, I tried it and the page stills the same.

Comment: A repository url can help dedug.

Comment: Get it ! Edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not used to the `_`

Comment: Usual mistakes are between keyboard and chair. ;-)